# Advanced database queries with Django

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite

Let's say I have a database called "A", this database has only two records "name: Jhon" and "name: Sara", and I also have the database "B" that has the names "Jhon" and "Sara" among other names, how can I search the database B only for the names Jhon and Sara?

Context: The database A has specific values, the database B is user generated, what I'm trying to accomplish is when the user-generated record to B database matches the A's record add some points to the user, it's like a game or something.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Seems pretty broad a question. Also, you seem to be confusing 'database' for 'table'.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm very noob about databases I don't know hoy a table would help

Comment: If you don't know "how a table would help", I urge you to put this whole thing off and dive into learning what databases are and how they work.

Comment: In this form, question is too borad. Title is misleading (advanced queries sounds like custom queries, ones you can not handle with current django db api). Also question and accepted answer is quite different. I advice you to read more about databases.

Voting for closure since the problem had solved and offers no future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a django model maps to a single database table.
Each attribute of the model represents a database field.

the following example [retrieve a list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) of names from the first [Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/) (named "A"), then [searches](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) into "B" for any record having the value of `name` attribute [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) that list.

```
names_to_search = A.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
people = B.objects.filter(name__in=names_to_search)
```

I assume that both A and B have a field called `name`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Sir!, Just one more question, what is flat=True?

Comment: If you only pass in a single field to values_list, you can also pass in the `flat` parameter. If `True`, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples. Please read the linked django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

Answer (score 0):

A database has tables, which have attributes.
In this case, you have 2 tables A and B.
You have "name" attribute for each table.

I do not understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to query a table with a name in Django,

```
person = A.objects.get(name=myName)
```

So if you want to know if Jhon is in table A,

```
try:
    person = A.objects.get(name="Jhon")
    #Jhon exists.
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    #Jhon does not exists.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But if I want to know if the Jhon in table A is also in the table B?